# How can I access localhost from another computer on a different network?

Tags: networking, localhost, wamp

Okay, please be patient with me as I am a completely green noob here.    Please assume in your answer that I know absolutely nothing about anything, because I don't.

Here is my specific situation.   I have downloaded WAMP, I have downloaded files to simulate a webpage and as per the instructions that came with the files, I placed them in the C:/wamp64/www folder.   Now when I navigate to "localhost" in my browser the page displays correctly.

How can I now send this link in an email so that someone can see the page the same way I do.  Or in other words, how can I create a link that the person receives it can access my localhost from a different network.

A couple of details here
- I am running windows 7 home 64bit
- The address in my browser reads localhost/#identifier, does it need to have a *.php extension and if so, how do I achieve that?
- I already edited the Apache file httpd-vhosts.conf from Require local to Require all granted

As it stands now, if I simply copy and paste the http://localhost/#identifier, all I get is "This site can't be reached.

### I know I am really noob here, but can anyone please help???

Comment: Either set WAMP to listen on all interfaces, configure your firewall to let the relevant port (80 probably) through, set your router to forward that port to your computer and either send your public IP (hoping it won't change in the meantime) or use a DynDNS service to get a domain name... or use a service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) which makes this all very simple and painless.

Comment: While I appreciate your help, None of that means much to me, as I know absolutely nothing about any of this.   I did try running ngrok, which seems to be running now, however I tried resending the link in an email and still cannot access it outside the network.    Does my original link look correct?   Should it have my IP in it?  Should it end in *.php?

Comment: How do I set WAMP to listen on all interfaces?   I have shut my firewall completely off for now. How do I set my router to forward that port to my computer?   I am truly sorry for my lack of knowledge here, I'm kind of looking for anyone that can step-by-step me through this if possible

Comment: I think I solved my own issue, or at least found a workaround.   I emailed my ip address instead of the http://localhost/ and it worked.   That may be only because ngrok is running for now, I guess we'll see.   Thanks again

Comment: Hm but if ngrok is running you'd need to send the URL returned by ngrok, not your IP...

Comment: Yes I was incorrect, it only appeared to be working because I could access it from my phone, which is on the same wifi.   I didn't even realize I needed a hosting service to host it on the web, I am learning a lot the past few days.   I have an updated thread with my current issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61354677/trying-to-host-my-localhost-on-the-internet-what-am-i-missing-here