# Trying to host my localhost on the internet. What am I missing here?

Tags: apache, server, localhost, wamp

Trying to get my localhost live on the web so anyone can access it.  I am a complete noob.  Here are the steps I have taken, running on a Windows 7, 64bit, with WAMP 2.4 & using noip.com

- Signed up for account with noip and downloaded DYC v4.1.1
- noip assigned me the hostname susanlafond.ddns.net with the ip/url 142.120.137.70
  [screenshot from noip.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwYmr.jpg)
- download WAMP server and installed
- Placed index files for my site in the www folder, and tested on browser as localhost, works fine
- Edited Apache httpd.conf.txt and made the following changes

  [apache screenshot (a)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jn67.jpg)
  [apache screenshot (b)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hBV2.jpg)
  [apache screenshot (c)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ds3wS.jpg)
  [apache screenshot (d)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0ys0.jpg)
- I ran apache port check and it reported my port 80 is used by apache, which i believe is correct
  [apache port 80 test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44yjJ.jpg)
- I went to my router settings and port forwarded port 80 on my ipv4 address
  [linksys router port forwarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOCZ8.jpg)
- Now at this point, keep in mind, I have no idea what I'm doing and I'm literally just following youtube tutorials to get this thing off the ground here.   But according to everything I've watched and read, I've done everything correctly.  When I go to 
  susanlafond.ddns.net from any browser I should be able to see my site being hosted on the internet, but I do not.
- A test of my url on an anonymous proxy site yielded these results:
  [zend2 url test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1f4q.jpg)
  and a portcheck on my public ip address shows no access to port 80, timed out
- Please help, I have no idea if this is even the right place to ask for help, I am so new at all of this, but time is of the essence here, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the `VirtualHost` directive, you need to have this instead:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName susanlafond.ddns.net 

    DocumentRoot C:\wamp\www

</VirtualHost>
```

The `VirtualHost` directive tells Apache, when this `ServerName` comes in on the 80 port, serve up the files in the `DocumentRoot`.

Otherwise, I believe you are nearly there.

Comment: +6499439/katie  thank you for your answer.  I have updated Apache now but I am still having the same issue.  I am 99 percent sure this has to do with ports not being open.   When I run Apache test port 80, its working.   I have Zanti on a rooted android, and when I scan my PC it shows me that p80 is open, however when I check p80 from canyouseeme.org it shows it as closed.   In fact when I check any port it shows them as closed.   Something is blocking the ports and I don't know what, I have disabled all firewalls, and Zanti is showing me that 80 is open.    I am pulling my hair out here

Comment: I'm just thinking here, that maybe Zanti is seeing the port as open because that device is on the same wifi.   ie; the port is open locally, but not to the internet still.  I have tried opening it on the router as well as running DMZ, both of which had the same results.   At this point I am 99 percent sure all my ports are being blocked by my ISP

Comment: Hi Sue,  yes, if the server you are trying to spin up is behind an ISP, it will not be a public facing server that lives in a data center with a publicly available IP address.